# Input a character pointer Array using Scanf , but when i input the String after "space" is truncated

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I want to input Character pointer Array, Using Scanf function when I run these snippets of code the input string after "space" the rest of String is Truncated :

[image]

I want to Print the Whole Input String

The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
    printf("Enter The String: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("The String is: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use format "%[^n]" to read all the line else the space is a separator, of use *fgets*

Comment: Don't use `scanf`, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` values 1 by definition. You will not go far allocating only 4 chars ... and why a `malloc` in your case an array in the stack is enough (and you forget to `free`)

Comment: If you use the idea from @bruno, it should be `" %[^\n]"` with 2 added characters to be the space-resistant equivalent of `"%s"`.

Comment: what if I really want to use scanf?

Comment: use `" %3[^\n]"` in that case, to not take the risk to write out of the array, and also check *scanf* returns 1

Comment: That's better yes. OP note the space before `%` to filter out previous newlines etc. Using `%` it stops at the first whitespace. That is its design.

Comment: @bruno i want to allocate bytes of memory , i mean i want to read 4 characters, that i used 4 in `malloc(sizeof(char)*4)`

Comment: @MuhammadSalman you said you want to read _Hello World_ because of the ending null char (never forgot it) you need  12 chars

Comment: how can i exactly Input String , while Exactly using the scanf @WeatherVane???

Comment: @MuhammadSalman replace your format with the one we propose, allocate 12 or more, compile then run. Of course in the format replace '3' by the size minus 1

Comment: Please read the comments again. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448196/input-a-character-pointer-array-using-scanf-but-when-i-input-the-string-after#comment108699654_61448196) allows a string containing spaces, for only 3 characters. For more, you need a bigger array.

Comment: @bruno you want me to multiply with 12, instead of 4?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman no need to multiply, as I said you  `sizeof(char)` values 1, not needed to multiply by 1, so `malloc(12)` or more

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I put an answer

Comment: @bruno Thanks it worked , But i want to know `%12[^\n]` why this format, instead of `%s`?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman I edited my answer with more details (they are already in the remarks we did on your question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  char *str = malloc(12);

  printf("Enter The String: ");
  if (scanf(" %11[^\n]", str) == 1)
    printf("The String is: %s\n", str);
  free(str);
  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall c.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter The String: Hello World
The String is: Hello World
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
Enter The String:    Hello World!
The String is: Hello World
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out < /dev/null
Enter The String: pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

In `scanf(" %11[^\n]", str)` :

- the space before '%' allows to bypass spaces (in the large sens of term, so also tab, newline etc) at the beginning of the line
- '11' limit the saving in *str* to 11 characters without counting the final null char also placed in *str*, else an input longer than 11 characters will write out of the array
- `[^\n]` allows to read up to the end of line (the newline is not saved), supposing it is not too long (see example with 'Hello World!'), the spaces inside the string are not considered as separator as this is the case with `%s`

Comment: `[^\n]` XOR the null character, I mean to exclude it from the input String?

Comment: @MuhammadSalman exclude and indicate when to stop to read. Change format to be `" %11[^o\n]"`  and enter 'hello world' at execution and you will see